# How can I use YAML anchors / override the Codedeploy block of code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

how can I use YAML anchors/override for AWS Codedeploy block of code and use a different DEPLOYMENT_GROUP? Is this possible? I have two deployment groups (staging and production deployment groups) that target one EC2 instance. I'm using bitbucket pipelines.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/

I'm getting an error with this kind of setup.
bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
    - step: &deploy
        name: Deploy to Staging
        deployment: Staging
        #trigger: manual     # Uncomment to make this a manual step
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - zip -r application1.zip .
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
            name: Upload to S3
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              APPLICATION_NAME: 'CodeDeployApp'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              COMMAND: 'upload'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application1.zip'
              VERSION_LABEL: 'app-1.0.0'
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
            name: Deploy to EC2
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              APPLICATION_NAME: 'CodeDeployApp'
              DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'staging-deployment-group'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              COMMAND: 'deploy'
              WAIT: 'true'
              VERSION_LABEL: 'app-1.0.0'
              IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
              FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
    master:
      - step: *build
      - step:
          <<: *deploy
          name: Deploy to Prod
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
          script:
            variables:
              DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'production-deployment-group'
```

Comment: Could you please reformat the code that it is correctly indented.